# How to handle saving on child context but the objected is already deleted in parent context?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, parent-child, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have core data nested contexts setup. Main queue context for UI and saving to SQLite persistent store. Private queue context for syncing data with the web service.

My problem is the syncing process can take a long time and there are the chance that the syncing object is deleted in the Main queue context. When the private queue is saved, it will crash with the "Core Data could not fulfill faulted" exception.

Do you have any suggestion on how to check this issue or the way to configure the context for handle this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic behind nested contexts. They don't solve a lot of problems related to concurrency without additional work. Many people (you seem to be one of those people) expect things to work out of the box which are not supposed to work. Here is a little bit of background information:

If you create a child context using the private queue concurrency type then Core Data will create a queue for this context. To interact with objects registered at this context you have to use either performBlock: or performBlockAndWait:. The most important thing those two methods do is to make sure to invoke the passed block on the queue of the context. Nothing more - nothing less.

Think about this for a moment in the context of a non Core Data based application. If you want to do something in the background you could create a new queue and schedule blocks to do work on that queue in the background. If your job is done you want to communicate the result of the background operations to another layer inside your app logic. What happens when the user deleted the object/data in the meantime which is related to the results from the background operation? Basically the same: A crash.

What you experience is not a Core Data specific problem. It is a problem you have as soon you introduce concurrency. What you need is to think about a policy or some kind of contract between your child and parent contexts. For example, before you delete the object from the root context you should cancel all of the operations/blocks which are running on other queues and wait for the cancellation to finish before you actually delete the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I want to know if there are any mechanism that CoreData provide for checking the existing of the data from the child context? Or any better solution.

Comment: You could use existingObjectWithID:error: (NSManagedObjectContext). Don't use objectWithID: in this case. But it is much better to have some kind of "sane" policy. Too much concurrency is harmful. Even with nested contexts and concurrency types Core Data and concurrency is only possible by thinking hard about your use cases. I am very sorry to be the messenger of bad news.